# Angular 9 call function from another component

Tags: angular

I have a component lets app-main which I'm already using it another component with its event emitter:

```
<app-dashboard (dateFrom)=OnDateFrom($event) ></app-dashboard>
```

In `<app-dashboard>` I have a function which is like this:

```
@Output() weatherResult= new EventEmitter<any>();

  SendWeatherResult(){

this.weatherResult.emit(results);
}
```

Now I need to call the `SendWeatherResult` function in my component

```
<app-dashboard (dateFrom)=OnDateFrom($event) //here i need to call this function></app-dashboard>
```

i want to call SendWeatherResult function in my app-main

Comment: Can you explain your intent better? When do you want to call that function?

Comment: @Yuri when i call this function it should pass me the result ,i dont need to pass any parameter,just need the result

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Explaination could be clearer, but maybe what you need is [template variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables):

```
<app-dashboard #appDashboard (dateFrom)=OnDateFrom($event)></app-dashboard>
<button (click)="appDashboard.SendWeatherResult()"> Send weather result</button>
```

If you want to use it from the component .ts, use [viewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild):

```
@ViewChild('appDashboard', { static: false }) appDashboard: DashboardComponent;

callSendWeatherResult(): void {
this.appDashboard.SendWeatherResult()
}
```

Comment: how you refer #appDashboard to the SendWeatherResult function?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. You want to call the function from the app-main component .ts, or the app-main component template ?

Comment: i want to call the function which is inside app-dashboard from app-main

Comment: that didn't answer my question, but i  edited my answer to add  an exemple as to how to call it from the .ts.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to go about this but when I need multiple components to be able to communicate and synchronize data between them, I prefer to create a global service.

[Stackblitz showing how this works.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qbbe6i)

**weather.service.ts** - Global service that can be accessed from any component.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class WeatherService {
  private _weatherResult = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  constructor() {
    this.methodToPopulateWeatherResult({ todayis: "sunny" });
  }

  weatherResult$(): Observable<any> {
    return this._weatherResult.asObservable();
  }

  methodToPopulateWeatherResult(report: any): void {
    this._weatherResult.next(report);
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts** - Shows how to access the weather results programatically using Observables.

```
import { Component, OnInit, VERSION } from "@angular/core";
import { distinctUntilChanged } from "rxjs/operators";
import { WeatherService } from "./weather.service";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <h3>Output from app-main</h3>
    {{ report | json }}

    <app-dashboard></app-dashboard>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  report: any;

  constructor(private weather: WeatherService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.weather
      .weatherResult$()
      .pipe(distinctUntilChanged())
      .subscribe((report: any) => {
        // Manipulate the updated weather report
        this.report = report;
      });
  }
}
```

**dashboard.component.ts** - Shows how to display the weather results directly in your template and a button to update the weather result globally.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { WeatherService } from "../weather.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-dashboard",
  template: `
    <h3>Output from app-dashboard</h3>
    <p>
      {{ weather.weatherResult$() | async | json }}
    </p>
    <button (click)="weather.methodToPopulateWeatherResult({ todayis: 'rainy' })">
      Make it Rain
    </button>
    <button (click)="weather.methodToPopulateWeatherResult({ todayis: 'snowy' })">
      Make it Snow
    </button>
  `
})
export class DashboardComponent {
  constructor(public weather: WeatherService) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question right.

I'm also new to angular but maybe this might work.

```
@Input()
SendWeatherResult(){

   return results;
}
```

```
<app-dashboard (dateFrom)=OnDateFrom($event)
               [(SendWeatherResult)]="saveReturnValueHere"></app-dashboard>
```